# How do you create a class using (admin.ModelAdmin) for a polling app

Tags: django

I am working through a Django tutorial at http://lightbird.net/dbe/todo_list.html . I completed Django's official tutorial. When I attempted to sync

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    priority = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    difficult = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["name", "priority", "difficult", "created", "done"]
    search_fields = ["name"]

admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdmin)
```

The terminal came back with an error that said admin was not defined. What am I doing wrong? How do I define admin?

Update: I added the whole models file as it looks now

Comment: You need to clarify, did you `from django.contrib import admin`?

Comment: Originally I imported models from django.db only, after I saw your response I added django.contrib import admin to the model and still go the same error

Comment: can you paste your imports into your question?

Answer (score 0):

[The Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) lists multiple steps that need to be done to activate the admin site:

> 1. **Add 'django.contrib.admin' to your INSTALLED_APPS setting**.
> 2. The admin has four dependencies - **django.contrib.auth, django.contrib.contenttypes, django.contrib.messages and
>      django.contrib.sessions**. If these applications are not in your
>      INSTALLED_APPS list, add them.
> 3. Add django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS and MessageMiddleware to
>      MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES. (These are both active by default, so you only
>      need to do this if you’ve manually tweaked the settings.)
> 4. Determine which of your application’s models should be editable in the admin interface.
> 5. For each of those models, optionally create a ModelAdmin class that encapsulates the customized admin functionality and options for
>      that particular model.
> 6. Instantiate an AdminSite and tell it about each of your models and ModelAdmin classes.
> 7. Hook the AdminSite instance into your URLconf. lists a couple of things that you must do the enable Django's admin site.

If you haven't done the first two items, `syncdb` might complain because it can't find the admin app itself.